Calculus: Is $(x-1)/f(x)$ decreasing?
Suppose $f$ is a continuous function and $f(x) \geq x-1$ for all $x>1$. It is also given that $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function in $x>1$. Can I say that
$$
\frac{x-1}{f(x)}\quad\text{is an monotonically decreasing function in $x>1$ ?}
$$

Using intermediate value theorem, I am able to  show that $g(x)$ is monotonic, I don’t know whether it increasing or decreasing.

I can't follow your argument in the differentiable case.  How does the logarithmic inequality imply what you claim?

Suppose $f(x)=(e^{-x}+1) (x-1)$.

To stress:  $f(x)>g(x)$ does not imply that $f'(x)>g'(x)$.

Instead of passing by derivates, can't you find something like $a \le b$ and $f(a) \le f(b)$, hence $\frac{a-1}{f(a)} \ge \frac{b-1)}{f(b)}$? (Something like that)

I got your point.

@Dominique I tried that.

@lulu thanks for valuable comments

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
The claim is false.  A simple counterexample is given by $$f(x)=(e^{-x}+1)(x-1)$$
The argument the OP invokes in the differentiable case is likewise false (as the counterexample shows).  Indeed, that argument is based on the false notion that $F(x)>G(x)\implies F'(x)>G'(x)$.

Thanks for your help again. One small question,  if $t-1\leq f(t) \leq t^2$ in my question, then what will happens? any idea.

My example satisfies that.
